How to add Horizontal strips in table css?
I've been trying to add a different colour to every n-th row. but when I added :nth-child property It gets applied to columns instead of rows. I have tried many solutions but none seem to work and I can't find the solution online either. Any answers would be much appreciated

I tried changing the tbody and tr and setting the styling to them, but to no avail. I want them to apply to every even-th row instead of column


table,
thead,
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: auto;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

th {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 16.7%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  width: 16.7%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

tbody {
  display: table;
}

tbody tr :nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #222831;
}

tbody tr :nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #31363F;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.no</th>
      <th>Visiter name</th>
      <th>Patient name</th>
      <th>reason</th>
      <th>enter time</th>
      <th>leave time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Guy 1</td>
      <td>Guy 2</td>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>12: 00am</td>
      <td>1: 30pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Guy 1</td>
      <td>Guy 2</td>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>12: 00am</td>
      <td>1: 30pm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Remove the space between tr and :nth-child in your CSS.
The selector tbody tr :nth-child(odd) looks for children/descendants of tr that are odd-numbered children. In this case, the odd-numbered tds are selected, not the odd-numbered trs. This applies styles makes every other cell of each row, which gives the appearance of styling every other column.
What you're looking for is the selector tbody tr:nth-child(odd), which looks for tr elements that also happen to be an odd-numbered child. This will style every other row.


table, thead, tbody{
    width: 100%;
}

table{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: auto;
}

tr{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

th{
    background-color: darkgray;
    width: 16.7%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

td {
    width: 16.7%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

tbody{
    display: table;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd){ /* no spaces between tr and :nth child */
    background-color: #222831;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #31363F;
}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th>Visiter name</th>
            <th>Patient name</th>
            <th>reason</th>
            <th>enter time</th>
            <th>leave time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Guy 1</td>
            <td>Guy 2</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td>12: 00am</td>
            <td>1: 30pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Guy 1</td>
            <td>Guy 2</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td>12: 00am</td>
            <td>1: 30pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Guy 1</td>
            <td>Guy 2</td>
            <td>example</td>
            <td>12: 00am</td>
            <td>1: 30pm</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




Hey! Thanks for the reply. Yeah it woks now. Just now realized it was a stupid mistake! Hahaha! anyway Thanks.
